# Current Status of the Riemann Hypothesis

Tags: nt.number-theory, riemann-zeta-function, riemann-hypothesis

Does anyone know the current progress in showing the Riemann hypothesis? I was only able to find [this](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-20/issue-1/At-least-two-fifths-of-the-zeros-of-the-Riemann/bams/1183554910.full) paper of Conrey that says at least 40% of the zeros of the Riemann Zeta function lie on the critical line.

Comment: What about results that say that the zeros all line a narrow, $\varepsilon$-strip about the critical line?

Comment: Any results are appreciated.

Comment: @David: I am pretty sure that such a strip is not known to exist. Proving that every zero has real part smaller than $\delta < 1$ would give an error term in the prime number theorem of $O(x^{\delta})$, which is certainly not known. The curve bounding the current known zero free region in fact approaches the line $s=1$ as $|t|\to \infty$.

Comment: A huge number of references are recorded here http://empslocal.ex.ac.uk/people/staff/mrwatkin//zeta/physics.htm, especially concerning the relation of RH to physics.

Comment: I am not sure that this question is appropriate for MO: it's ways too wide and unspecific. Before opening it, the title give the impression that someone came up with a proof of RH, and that the PO was asking about the status of that proof. RH is probably the most famous 
open problem in mathematics. Any serious progress on it would be
almost immediately reported on say, the wikipedia page on RH, and on
many other places. A more legitimate question would be something more specific, like "is it known that 40% of the zeros are on the critical line, and if known, where can I find a reference?".

Comment: There is a fun experiment to have non-mathematicians explore (and attempt to prove) the Riemann Hypothesis: http://fadereu.posterous.com/pages/frequently-asked-questions My reaction, that the organiser endorsed, was why should only mathematicians get the pleasure of failing to prove the Riemann Hypothesis? 

Comment: @ David: It has been known for nearly 100 years that "almost all" zeros are in such a strip. This goes back to Bohr and Landau's work on the zeta-function.

Comment: @Joel: A question along a similar vein regarding the BSD conjecture was posted (http://mathoverflow.net/questions/11502/the-current-status-of-the-birch-swinnerton-dyer-conjecture) but in this case wasn't considered to be off-topic, right down to the title. However in this case considering the quality of answers I've been receiving, I'm for closing this question down.

Comment: @Joel: Also, wikipedia isn't very up to date on this subject as only Conrey's 1989 paper (which I referenced here) is mentioned in it.

Comment: Why not ask Cam Stewart, or one of the other number theorists at UW?

Comment: Dear Eugene, don't take it personally. You do ask good questions 
on that forum. I just think that this specific question was too wide. RH is a field of research in itself (with many aspects and angle of attacks) so asking in general about "current progress on RH" is a little bit like asking "Hi. Any current progress in algebra ?", or pushing it a little bit farther like "hey guys, what's up (in mathematics)?". 

Comment: @Joel: Oh sorry if it came off as me taking it personally. I understand what you are saying. Some of the answers here really show I could've been more focused in my question.

Comment: Eugene, it appears you have been on MO for just 60 days or the like, that is from your profile information. As far as history, some of our most pernicious cranks have asked questions in the same areas you are asking about, precisely because these are some of the biggest unsolved problems. If you would like more detail on that email me (or maybe Yemon). Meanwhile, I'd like to encourage you to see MO as less of an encyclopedia about exciting problems, and more of a resource when you are stuck in your own work. In short, questions on RH and BSD make me nervous.

Comment: @Will: Again I apologize for any trouble I have caused. I'm currently writing my masters thesis on a paper which assumes GRH, BSD and ABC conjecture and I am looking for up-to-date developments on these problems. I'm really not up to any crankery here. If it was inappropriate of me to ask about them I apologize once again.

Comment: Eugene, it's nice to know your actual situation. If you simply put your new comment in the text of a question, it will help people give you better answers. It makes all the difference that you are writing something that includes, say, the status of these problems. 

Comment: @Will: At the suggestion of Yemon I have emailed Professor Stewart about this. I don't mind if this question stays shut. Some of the answers here have left me feeling cold.

Comment: Eugene, makes sense. I guess what I can offer is a pre-editing service. I have a gmail account, if you email me with a preliminary version of a question and some information, I can mush together a question that will work. Not that I know anything about these subjects themselves. As many have commented, including Richard Borcherds, it is difficult to make a good MO question. He is setting pretty high standards for "good," of course.

Comment: @Will: Thanks for the offer but I think I'll just wait for Professor Stewart's reply.

Comment: The Riemann Hypothesis: A Resource for the Afficionado and Virtuoso Alike text published by the CMS authored by Borwein, Choi, Rooney, and Weirathmueller has a great summary up to 2004. Combined with Mark Lewko's wonderful response I think I have my answer now. Thanks all.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In terms of fraction of zeros on the critical line (which seems to be your question), the best result to date is 41.05% by Bui, Conrey and Young ("[More than 41% of the zeros of the zeta function are on the critical line](https://arxiv.org/abs/1002.4127)" arXiv:1002.4127). Of course, this is only one measure of progress.

Answer (score 7):

It is unsolved as of today.

However, some latest researches are:

- [A paper from 2002 talks by Freeman J. Dyson on Random Matrix Theory, Quasicrystals and zeta function](http://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Eoyounggo/books/dyson.pdf) ([Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20120710025614/https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/%7Eoyounggo/books/dyson.pdf))
- [Fractal Geography of the Riemann Zeta Function](https://dhushara.com/DarkHeart/geozeta/zetageo.htm)
- Andrew Odlyzko's [collection of papers on such topic](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/%7Eodlyzko/doc/zeta.html)

**Edit**:

FWIW, do note that the shortest "proof" of RH by Mark Colyvan as mentioned in [IEP here](https://iep.utm.edu/para-log/#SH2a) using *paraconsistent logic*:<br

> As the founders of relevant logic,
> Anderson and Belnap, urge in their
> canonical book Entailment, a ‘proof’
> submitted to a mathematics journal in
> which the essential steps fail to
> provide a reason to believe the
> conclusion, e.g. a proof by explosion,
> would be rejected out of hand. Mark
> Colyvan (2008) illustrates the point
> by noting that no one has laid claim
> to a startlingly simple proof of the
> Riemann hypothesis:
>
> **Riemann’s Hypothesis**: All the zeros of the zeta function have real part equal to > 1/2. 
> **Proof**: Let R stand for the Russell set, the set of all sets that are not
> members of themselves. It is
> straightforward to show that this set
> is both a member of itself and not a
> member of itself. Therefore, all the
> zeros of Riemann’s zeta function have
> real part equal to 1/2.
>
> Needless to say, the Riemann
> hypothesis remains an open problem at
> time of writing.

The cited [2008 article by Colyvan](http://homepage.mac.com/mcolyvan/papers/waoim.pdf) however does not use this for RH but Fermat's Last Theorem.

Speaking of **non-classical approach**, Douglas S. Bridges further writes about the self-referential nature in *[Reality and Virtual Reality in Mathematics (2006)](https://www.math.canterbury.ac.nz/%7Ed.bridges/files/real.pdf)*:

> There is an even more dramatic example of a proof which might cause the
> same unease. A famous conjecture of Riemann in the nineteenth century, the
> Riemann Hypothesis, remains unsolved today despite the efforts of some of the
> greatest mathematicians in the intervening 150 years. Early last century, the
> English mathematician J.E. Littlewood produced a theorem whose difficult proof
> was split into two cases. In the first case, Littlewood assumed that the Riemann
> Hypothesis was true, and in the second that it was false. Writing R to denote the
> Riemann Hypothesis, and P to denote the conclusion of Littlewoods theorem,
> we can express his proof in the schematic form
> $(R\bigvee\neg R)\Rightarrow P.$ (1)
> Here I have introduced the standard logical symbols $\bigvee$ (or), $\neg$ (not), and $\Rightarrow$ (implies)
> What is the meaning of Littlewoods proof? Since we are unable at this
> date to decide whether or not the Riemann Hypothesis is true, we cannot say
> which of the two cases of his proof actually applies. If, as most mathematicians
> expect, the Riemann Hypothesis turns out to be provable, then that part of
> Littlewoods proof that is based on the assumption that the Riemann Hypothesis
> is false is worthless and can be thrown away. Moreover, in such a proof, if $P$
> is an existential statement one that asserts the existence of a certain object
> $x$ with certain properties then the two cases of a proof of $P$ that follows the
> Littlewoods schematic form (1) may produce different objects $x$ with the desired
> properties (as in our earlier proof involving $\sqrt{2}^{\sqrt{2}}$
> ); under such circumstances, we
> might be unable to tell which of the two possibilities for x was the desired one
> until we could prove the truth or falsity of the Riemann Hypothesis.
> The formalist might attempt to remove our unease about Littlewoods proof
> as follows. Suppose that the desired conclusion $P$ of Littlewoods theorem is false.
> Then Littlewoods arguments, schematised in (1), show that neither the Riemann
> Hypothesis nor its negation can hold (since each of these alternatives leads us
> to a proof of $P$): In other words, if $P$ is false, then the Riemann Hypothesis is
> false and it is false that the Riemann Hypothesis is false! This is plainly absurd.
> Hence we conclude that $P$ cannot be false and is therefore true.

Comment: +1 for your first sentence!